# Оптимизация таблицы MySQL

Tags: mysql, оптимизация, c++, sql

Имею таблицу, в ней есть туча строк. Все имеют уникальный id. после ошибки в программе имею примерно такие вот id 14531887, но в таблице есть и id 200350, после него и начинаются большие. Как можно урезать все id, которые больше  200350, тоесть к примеру из 14531887 сделать 531887, или лучше 214531. Может кто сталкивался, прошу помощи.

Comment: Вам нужны id, которые будут идти строго по порядку? не нужно переживать по этому поводу. На то они и id. Их переделывать не нужно - они обычно служат для связи с другими таблицами.

Comment: Оставьте как есть. Это не номера, а уникальные идентификаторы. Если нужны номера для использования в программе, заведите отдельную колонку.

Кстати, как формируются ID? По-хорошему, должны формироваться с помощью последовательностей (sequence).

Comment: После просчета программы получилось вот так, те что с малыми id, связаны с другими данными, а те что большие существую лишь для различия их друг от друга. Урезать мне их просто необходимо!